# Find average value within different JSON objects

Tags: javascript

I have a JSON object which is as follows, it consists of an id, and object measurements.
Object measurements consists of Tastiness which has its respective taste for each level, such as level 25,50, and 100. I'm trying to combine the tastiness into 1 value with the average of each taste level (for example total of sourness / objectMeasurements number)

```js
  "objectId": "de8e783a-1a13-42be-b1b2-1bc7be24b511"
  "objectMeasurements": [
            {
                "id": "f986cb0d-a9f2-4d8f-ad2f-9ff46e097764",
                "data": {
                    "scale": 5,
                    "tastiness": [
                        {
                            "level": 100,
                            "sourness": 4,
                            "freshness": 5,
                            "sweetness": 3
                        },
                        {
                            "level": 25,
                            "sourness": 4,
                            "freshness": 3,
                            "sweetness": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "level": 50,
                            "sourness": 3,
                            "freshness": 5,
                            "sweetness": 5
                        }
                    ]
                },
            },
            {
                "id": "12efc22b-ff69-4248-8b25-4ed8981089df",
                "data": {
                    "scale": 5,
                    "tastiness": [
                        {
                            "level": 100,
                            "sourness": 3,
                            "freshness": 5,
                            "sweetness": 5
                        },
                        {
                            "level": 25,
                            "sourness": 5,
                            "freshness": 4,
                            "sweetness": 4
                        },
                        {
                            "level": 50,
                            "sourness": 4,
                            "freshness": 5,
                            "sweetness": 3
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
```

How is it possible for me to combine the data tastiness and get the average of each property, into 1 object measurement such as something like this

```js
  "objectId": "de8e783a-1a13-42be-b1b2-1bc7be24b511"
  "objectMeasurements": [
            {
                "id": "someId",
                "data": {
                    "scale": 5,
                    "tastiness": [
                        {
                            "level": 100,
                            "sourness": 3.5,
                            "freshness": 2,
                            "sweetness": 4
                        },
                        {
                            "level": 25,
                            "sourness": 4.5,
                            "freshness": 3.5,
                            "sweetness": 4.5
                        },
                        {
                            "level": 50,
                            "sourness": 3.5,
                            "freshness": 2,
                            "sweetness": 4
                        }
                    ]
                },
            },
```

Comment: Loop through the array elements, summing the values and then dividing by the number of elements. That's the normal way to calculate an average.

Comment: do you want to merge all objects inside `objectMeasurements` into an array of objects grouped by `level`..? so you don't need properties `id`, `scale`, `tastiness`...?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = {
    "objectId": "de8e783a-1a13-42be-b1b2-1bc7be24b511",
    "objectMeasurements": [{
        "id": "f986cb0d-a9f2-4d8f-ad2f-9ff46e097764",
        "data": {
            "scale": 5,
            "tastiness": [{
                "level": 100,
                "sourness": 4,
                "freshness": 5,
                "sweetness": 3
            }, {
                "level": 25,
                "sourness": 4,
                "freshness": 3,
                "sweetness": 5
            }, {
                "level": 50,
                "sourness": 3,
                "freshness": 5,
                "sweetness": 5
            }]
        },
    }, {
        "id": "12efc22b-ff69-4248-8b25-4ed8981089df",
        "data": {
            "scale": 5,
            "tastiness": [{
                "level": 100,
                "sourness": 3,
                "freshness": 5,
                "sweetness": 5
            }, {
                "level": 25,
                "sourness": 5,
                "freshness": 4,
                "sweetness": 4
            }, {
                "level": 50,
                "sourness": 4,
                "freshness": 5,
                "sweetness": 3
            }]
        }
    }]
}


let res = {}

input.objectMeasurements.map(obj => {

    obj.data.tastiness.map((m) => {

        const keys = Object.keys(m);

        keys.map(key => {

            if (key !== 'level') {

                if (!res[(m.level)].count[key]) {

                    res[(m.level)].count[key] = res[(m.level)].totals[key] = 0;
                }

                res[(m.level)].count[key]++;
                res[(m.level)].totals[key] += m[key];

            } else {
                if (!res[(m.level)]) {
                    res[(m.level)] = {
                        count: {},
                        totals: {}
                    }
                }
            }

        });

    });
});


let tastiness = [];

Object.keys(res).reverse().map(levelKey => {

    let avg = {};

    avg.level = +levelKey;

    Object.keys(res[levelKey].count).map(tasteKey => {

        avg[tasteKey] = res[levelKey].totals[tasteKey] / res[levelKey].count[tasteKey];
    });
    tastiness.push(avg);

});

input.objectMeasurements = tastiness;

console.log(input);
```